# Construct by hand a Perceptron which correctly classifies the following data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I am beginner in Machine learning. I am trying to solve perceptron problem by hand for following data
Training example        [x1 x2] [0 1] [2 0] [1 0] Class [1 -1]

using a learning rate of 1.0 and initial weight values of  w0 = -1.5  w1 =   0  w2 =   2

I have solved this for epochs but it is not converging. I am unable to figure out where I am doing wrong Please see attached picture I solved by hand

[I tried to solve this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRkQb.jpg)